# Why aren't migrated questions erased from the origin site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have asked a question that was migrated to its meta site. but the main question remained there and every time I search it by its question ID, I can reach it.

Is it OK not to erase the question from the origin site?

What if someone accidentally closes the migrated question because it is a duplicate of the first question?

Comment: IIRC they are eventually deleted (30 days); can you link the example?

Comment: aminabzz  You said "I have asked a question that was migrated to its meta site."  Do you mean you asked a question on math.se, and it was migrated to this meta site (meta.math.se)?  I ask because you say: "

"I have asked a question that was migrated to **its** meta site." But you don't mention the site on which you asked your question, and when you refer to "its" meta site, it makes me wonder whether you are asking about a question you asked on another SE site, which was migrated to **its** meta site.

Comment: In my experience when a Question is migrated, searching "by its Question ID" results in being redirected to the site to which it was migrated.  It would make your Question above clearer if you provided the requested *link* to the example.  Once a Question is migrated you do not need to worry about "eras[ing] the question from the origin[al] site."

Comment: The [FAQ post on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249) mentions that: "The question is left as a stub, or pathway to the new site, for 30 days, after which it is automatically deleted." You can find there also many other details related to migration stubs and migrations in general.